Does a MOSFET draw current from its gate?
I understood that a MOSFET does not draw current from its gate, and only depends on gate voltage.  However, this simple MOSFET circuit shows that when R1 is very low (1 ohm), it works fine, but when R1 is even 1K ohm, it fails to operate.  How is that possible?

With R1 at 1K, the amplifier fails:

Lowering R1 to 1 ohm solves it.  Why?


A MOSFET gate is a capacitor, and capacitors require current to charge and discharge. In combination with the gate resistance, this forms an RC lowpass filter. If the gate resistance is large, and the input frequency high enough, it may not be able to charge up enough for a large output shift before the input signal pulls it low again.
If you set that frequency lower, your amplifier will still work even with 1 kΩ gate resistance.
When engineers say that a MOSFET doesn't require gate current, we mean that it doesn't require steady-state gate current, in contrast to BJTs, which do. Charging and discharging the gate does still require some current, and can be a major source of losses in higher-frequency switching converters.

Fascinating.  Is it correct to state that it's as if there's a capacitor between the gate and the source, acting as a HPF to ground? How would you modify the circuit to handle this? Would adding resistance between the source and ground be a good solution?

@SRobertJames Not "as if"; there literally is. I said the gate is a capacitor for a reason--it's a conductor-insulator-(semi)conductor stack, with a fairly large area (for high-current devices) and very thin (measured in Å) insulator. The solution is to simply not use such a high gate resistance--you don't need it here. You could use no resistor at all, even, and the circuit would work fine.

Got it.  I put in the R1 to simulate source impedance.  Won't the circuit fail if the source has any impedance at all? I assume a real source will have some impedance.

@SRobertJames A good voltage source will have very low output impedance. If the output impedance of the source is too high, you may need a current amplifier stage before your voltage amplifier stage. You can also use a smaller MOSFET, with correspondingly smaller input capacitance (which is always included on datasheets as Ciss, usually but not always in the "dynamic characteristics" section).

Yes a MOSFET gate does draw current, and the amount of charge that will flow when flipping the transistor (total integrated current) is actually a key parameter when picking out a MOSFET:

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd87503q3e.pdf
In this case the vendor has listed it second only to the voltage on the product summary.  The lower the charge required, the higher the source impedance driving the MOSFET can be to obtain a certain transition time.
